# Very simple image slider with Jquery not sliding whole width of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I made a simple image slider to show the houses at sale of a properties website, but the slider doesn't slide the whole width of the divs containing the images. I made a codepen at 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eamns to illustrate what I mean, does someone know how can I slide the element without leaving a small bit of it visible? Somehow I don't like to use the whole lot of sliders that are out there, but building my own. I'll appreciate any help, as you can see I'm using the outerWidth and margin properties to determine the distance of the slide, but it's not very clean and I still don't like it.

Thanks in advance

```
  [1]: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eamns
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your CodePen is complete. If you want something clean and easy to implement, I recommend using the 'jquery cycle' plug-in (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) to create your slider. It is the easiest way I have found to make many types of image sliders.

Comment: thanks @Mookstock for answering, I'll check it though as I said I was rather looking for a comment on my own solution. The codepen is complete, (sigh) but it looks incomplete as the solution isn't clean already

Comment: Totally understand about wanting to work through it from scratch. I used to do that myself, but found that Cycle saved me a ton of time and can be very simple or quite robust if needed. Sorry I ddi not get you exactly what you wanted... Best of luck to you!

Comment: @gerardoflores - Took another look and it seems that your slider may not work in Chrome. I could be wrong... In FireFox I could see your issue though. Taking a quick glance it just appears that the outerWidth is not giving the proper width, and this is causing the 'paso' variable to come up a little short. The width should be 298px, in fact since the slides are all the same width, if I set paso to 298px the slider works great!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the images in the slider will be of variable width so I was looking for a property that should work in a cross browser way. Seems like outerWidth with the true parameter should be the one, to include the margin of the element. But it's not working as expected.